# Failed to resolve variable when migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I tried migrating to `AndroidX` but I get these errors when building Gradle. And it's odd since I do not always get the errors and I do not know where the errors are from, so I can't really which solution from SO answers solve the issue. I found that plenty of people experience this but most answers on SO suggests to either `clean, rebuild, invalidate caches/restart, or update other dependencies`. The `clean, rebuild, invalidate caches/restart` is a temporary solution but if updating other dependencies solve it, how do I find which dependencies need to be updated?

**Error:**

```
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
```

Comment: Which dependencies you have? Can you show here?

Comment: pass the dependencies on your build.graddle module app. looks like you are missing all those variables.

Comment: post gradle of your project

Comment: Try Invalidate caches  and restart the project  File --> Invalidate caches/restart

Comment: @StavroXhardha How do you mean? the dependencies I use are all in module gradle.

Comment: @Dulanga I have already done that and it seems to work temporarily.